# How to use a different timezone to the browser timezone?

Tags: javascript

We are working on application in which I need to display all the date in a custom timezone. I use external libraries (GWT...) in which javascript Date is used. I can't override the GWT code. Moreover the javascript Date seems to be the better place to set the custom timezone. 
We tried first to override the "accessors"  using the prototype mechanism :

```
var original_getUTCHours = Date.prototype.getUTCHours;
Date.prototype.getUTCHours = function(){
    // -4 for the time zone offset
    return original_getUTCHours.call(this)-4;
}
var myDate = new Date();
alert(myDate.getUTCHours());
```

But this mechanism seems to be long to implement because there is a lot of "accessors" to override. Each accessor need a specific algorithm to process the offset.

So We tried to ovveride the Date constructor using the prototype mechanism.

```
var original_date_constructor = Date.prototype.constructor;

function Date(){
    var now = original_date_constructor;
    original_date_constructor(now.getUTCFullYear(),now.getUTCMonth(),now.getUTCDate(),now.getUTCHours()-4,now.getUTCMinutes(),now.getUTCSeconds(),now.getUTCMilliseconds())
}
```

But we get this error, in the Chrome debugger :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function Date(){

var now = original_date_constructor;
original_date_constructor(now.getUTCFullYear(),now.getUTCMonth(),now.getUTCDate(),now.getUTCHours()-4,now.getUTCMinutes(),now.getUTCSeconds(),now.getUTCMilliseconds());
} has no method 'getUTCFullYear'
```

Is it possible to override the Date constructor and what is the right way ?

Thanks

Comment: You should not overwrite the Date constructor. Never. Instead, use UTC dates and bring in the timezone only for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-apply the `Date` prototype:

```
Date.prototype = original_date_constructor.prototype;
```

Comment: When i need to re-apply the prototype ? could you provide a complete example ?